# Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools Comparison Mappings

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Does Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools (any version) support changing the default comparison mappings, for objects with different names, and/or in different schemas?

For example, I want to compare tables in two SQL Server databases, but the tables are in different schemas in each database:

database1.**SchemaA**.MyTable

database2.**SchemaB**.MyTable

Can these tables be compared with each other using SSDT, and if so how can I do it? I cannot find any mapping options or documentation.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution back then? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236164/comparing-schemas-ignoring-the-schema-name

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't find a way to do this with SSDT. I ended up using the Redgate comparison tools instead, which do support this type of comparison.

Comment: @MJ too bad :-(   Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no, you cannot do the comparison using `SSDT` if they are in different `schema`. The `database` doesn't matter though, you could specify the `connection` and `database` when running `schema compare`, but not the `schema`.

One *workaround* to get it working in less than ideal way would be to:

- deploy your SchemaA.MyTable locally
- after the schema has been deployed successfully, replace the table definition of SchemaA.MyTable with that of SchemaB.MyTable
- Run `sqlcompare` with your project as the source and the local db (where you deployed your project in step 1) as the target.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but would like something a little more easily repeatable. I'm thinking I'll probably just need to use a different comparison tool.