# Comparing schemas ignoring the schema name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare

I'm using the SQL Server Data Tools to compare the tables two schemas. The schemas are similar and should be adapted to be the same. Now my problem is, that those two schemas are differently named.

Example:

```
[sourceDB]
    [FOO].[table1]
    [FOO].[table2]

[targetDB]
    [BAR].[table1]
    [BAR].[table2]
```

When I run the compare, it wants to remove both tables in schema `BAR` and recreate them with schema `FOO`. What I want is to just compare both tables regardless of the schema name and get a script that alters the tables in schema `BAR`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Huh??? I can't wrap my head around what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @SeanLange Very simple SSDT allows you to compare schema between different DBs. OP wants to compare objects in different schemas not databases.

Comment: @SeanLange I will try to rephrase it a little

Comment: @lad2025 that makes sense. Wasn't getting that for some reason. >.<

Comment: @lad2025 couldn't have said it better (obviously). Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that you can use SSDT to compare two schemas within the same database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools Comparison Mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439613/visual-studio-sql-server-data-tools-comparison-mappings)